# Can I use resized model for partial select?

Tags: sql, go

I have legacy code where `SELECT * FROM users` retrieves a lot of fields (more than 100) and maps to my model but my service code in this handler depends on 8 fields.

How to handle this situation? Should I map selected fields to this model partially (leaving other fields with default values) or create a new model specifically for this handler and then map everything to it? What is the best way to handle such situations?

Comment: You can select only the fields you want.

Comment: You can modify your query to only select the relevant columns; you will need to consider how your scanning the result into the struct though. If you are for example depending on `database/sql`'s `Rows.Scan`, the number of values you're scanning into must be the same as the number of columns in the result set. See also: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan